# Getting a list of all current scalar variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
IF @tabla IS NULL
BEGIN
      Declare @tabla VARCHAR(50)
END
```

Of course this gives me the undecleared variable error in sql, so I thought if there is a temp table like tempdb for scalar variables I could just look for the actaul name "tabla" in this table.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not a view to find variables in code. Variables that are not declared will prevent the code to compile and, therefore, to be stored. If you want to find a definition of the variable used in different code, you would need to search for it in the whole code which might give you false positives.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%@tabla[^A-Za-z0-9]%'
```

The only thing that gets close to storing variables, is the `sys.parameters` table. But as the name states, it only shows parameters.

```
SELECT o.name AS ObjectName,
        p.name AS ParameterName,
        p.parameter_id,
        t.name AS type,
        p.max_length,
        p.precision, p.scale,
        p.is_output,
        p.has_default_value,
        p.is_nullable
        --,any other columns
FROM sys.parameters p
JOIN sys.objects    o ON p.object_id = o.object_id
JOIN sys.types      t ON p.user_type_id = t.user_type_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Must declare the scalar variable "@tabla"

As the error states, you have to declare the "@tabla" before your IF statement. You wont be able to achieve this even after you look for the correct "tabla" name from system table. The scope of the variable last for the duration the stored procedure.